# X-axis and Y-axis labels are not displaying in NVD3 for multibarchart(bar chart and stackedbar chart)

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

i am facing issue in d3.v3.js when it is called from axis.js of nvd3 library, exception( **undefined is not a function** ) is in d3.svg.axis function

the exception raised is  due to this line (**call(chart)** method)

```
d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(data).transition().duration(500).call(chart);
```

the piece of code which i am using is

```
var chart;
    nv.addGraph(function() {
      chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()           
        .color(["#44545F", "#628696", "#2DADBD", "#18CBE7"])
        .margin({bottom: 100})
        .transitionDuration(300)
        .delay(1000)
        .rotateLabels(45)
        .showLegend(true)  
        .showControls(true)
        //.stacked(true)
        .groupSpacing(0.2)
        .showXAxis(true)
        .showYAxis(true);

      chart.multibar.hideable(true);

      chart.reduceXTicks(false) ////If 'false', every single x-axis tick label will be rendered.
      .staggerLabels(true);

      chart.xAxis
          .axisLabel("Current Index")
          .showMaxMin(true).tickFormat(d3.format("s"));
          //.tickFormat(d3.format(',.9f'));

      chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));          

      d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(data).transition().duration(500).call(chart);

      nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

      chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

      return chart;
    });
```

exception in d3.v3.js is on this line

```
    tickEnter = tick.enter().insert("g", "path").attr("class", "tick major").style("opacity", 1e-6)
```

the screenshot is as foolows

[image]

Comment: Can you post the contents of your data variable

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?